# Sobre el uso de la coma opcional

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Es frecuente encontrar oraciones de este tipo:

*al final del día( ) Juan se despide de su mamá con un beso ( ) en la mejilla.*

En el primer paréntesis, usualmente no se usa la coma, pero es obvio que hay una pausa al leer esa parte de la oración. En el segundo ( ), puede o no puede haber una pausa al leer aunque el significado no cambio entre la pausa y la no pausa. En estos casos, ¿podríamos decir que la coma es opcional o, simplemente, es un error colocar comas en esas circunstancias?

Comment: La primera coma de tu ejemplo **no es opcional**. La segunda coma **es incorrecta**. Hay reglas al respecto.

Comment: Rodrigo, mira la respuesta. Dices que la primera no es opcional y que la segunda es incorrecta. Todo bien, pero lamentablemente no explicas la razón.

Comment: OK, disculpa. Trataba de decirte que tu pregunta se basa en suposiciones incorrectas y que tienes que tratar de conocer las reglas de uso. Éstas están en el link a la RAE de la respuesta de AlexBcn. Para la primera coma de tu ejemplo, el punto 1.2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay unas normas en la RAE, pero también aparece en su definición: *"No siempre su presencia responde a la necesidad de realizar una pausa en la lectura y, viceversa, existen en la lectura pausas breves que no deben marcarse gráficamente mediante comas. Aunque en algunos casos el usar la coma en un determinado lugar del enunciado puede depender del gusto o de la intención de quien escribe, existen comas de presencia obligatoria en un escrito para que este pueda ser correctamente leído e interpretado."*

Puede ponerse en la primera, y en la segunda si quieres destacar que es en la mejilla, quizás el día anterior no se despidió igual...

[RAE: coma](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=COMA)

Para usos incorrectos de la coma fijate al final del enlace.